# Normalize volume in a 32 bit PCM Wav with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Is there a way to normalize volume in a 32-bit wav file using NAudio?

If the volume is clipping, then I want a downward normalize and vice versa if the volume is too low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in feature, but if you use `AudioFileReader` you can examine the values of all samples to find the max absolute sample value. From this you can work out how much the original file can be amplified by without clipping.

Then you can use the `Volume` property of `AudioFileReader` to amplify the audio, and then use `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile` to write that out to a new (IEEE floating point) WAV file. `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16` could be used if you wanted a 16 bit output after normalizing.

Here's some very simple sample code

```
var inPath = @"E:\Audio\wav\input.wav";
var outPath = @"E:\Audio\wav\normalized.wav";
float max = 0;

using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(inPath))
{
    // find the max peak
    float[] buffer = new float[reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate];
    int read;
    do
    {
        read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        for (int n = 0; n < read; n++)
        {
            var abs = Math.Abs(buffer[n]);
            if (abs > max) max = abs;
        }
    } while (read > 0);
    Console.WriteLine($"Max sample value: {max}");

    if (max == 0 || max > 1.0f)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("File cannot be normalized");

    // rewind and amplify
    reader.Position = 0;
    reader.Volume = 1.0f / max;

    // write out to a new WAV file
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outPath, reader);
}
```

Comment: It works nicely but it makes my file huge, from 10mb as original to 269mb... any idea why? can I solve it?

Comment: seems like the file remains like in real mode and I need to compress it, any idea how to get that done or another way to get it back to normal?

Comment: I've been implementing this piece of code and it did normalized my files. However, it seems like it "twisted" something that prevents my code to work with the normalized file. Could it be that the header has been changed?
I'm converting MP3 file to WAV using FFMPEG and then run the NAudio normalization method.

FFMpeg arguments:
-i "input.mp3" -codec:a pcm_s16le -ar 8000 "output.wav"
header beginning before and after normalization:

Original:
RIFFF3 WAVEfmt      @  €>    LIST   INFOISFT   Lavf57.66.101 **data** ...
Normalized:
RIFF&3 WAVEfmt      @  €>      **data** ...